# create dynamically table and add image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to create a table of 3 cards like X X X 
I cant add any rows or columns 
all need to be dynamically so the body is empty:

```
<script>
    var $card = $('<div />').appendTo('body');
    var $table = document.createElement("table");
    var $image = document.createElement("IMG");
    $('#table').find('body').append("<tr>");
    $('#table').find('body').append("<td>" + $image.src + "</td>");
    $('#table').find('body').append("<td>" + $image.src + "</td>");
    $('#table').find('body').append("<td>" + $image.src + "</td>");
    $('#card').html($table);
    $card.append($table);
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $image.src = "/images/ACE.jpg";
        $('#card').html($image);
        $card.append($image);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `body` is a child of `document`.  So trying to find body off of a table is not valid.  Are you sure you didn't mean those to be `tbody`?

Comment: It also appears that you are operating off of the assumption that you are generating markup.  You are appending a tr, then a td, and another td and so on.  But this is not the case.  When you append something to the DOM, you are creating DOM Elements, which do not have an opening tag and closing tag.  HTML is just used as a method of defining DOM elements in the source.  When you are adding elements to the DOM directly, this is no longer the case.  You have to append the elements to their parents directly, or build out the entire markup as you want it, before appending all of it.

Comment: i just starting to programming so any example will be good for me :)

Comment: Which part exactly are you having an issue with?  Rather than asking "how do I make this work" ask specifically about an issue that you are having trouble fixing/understanding.

Comment: if i want to add the image to a table i should :1)create table 2)append tr to table 3)append td to table 4)append image to each tr 5)add the table to $card or to body?

Comment: You don't append a td to the table.  You append the td to the tr.  You also append the image to a td.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to generate elements in the DOM, you have to append them to the element that they are expected to be children of.  This is a basic example of creating elements and appending them to their parent.  This should hopefully give you an idea of how your logic could work.

```js
var $body = $(document.body);

//make a table
var $table = $('<table>');
//make a row
var $row = $('<tr>');
//make a column
var $col = $('<td>');
//put something in the column
$col.append('Hey there!');
//put the column in the row
$row.append($col);
//put the row in the table
$table.append($row);
//put the table in the body
$body.append($table);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or you could build the markup first as a string before you ever append it.

```js
var $body = $(document.body);
var html = '';

//make a table
html += '<table>';
//make a row
html += '<tr>';
//make a column
html += '<td>';
//put something in the column
html += 'Hey there!';
//close the column
html += '</td>';
//close the row
html += '</tr>';
//close the table
html += '</table>';
//put the table in the body
$body.append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating invalid HTML. Also you're mixing incomplete JavaScript code with jQuery. Add a table to the `body`, then add a `tr` row to the table, then add three `td` cells to the row. Your images should go into the cells. Here is a simple code to do so:

```js
var img = '<img src="/images/ACE.jpg" />';
var table = $('<table id="table1"></table>').appendTo('body');
table.append("<tr></tr>");
table.find('tr').append("<td>" + img + "</td>"
                      + "<td>" + img + "</td>"
                      + "<td>" + img + "</td>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```